# Local truncation error for IVP with time-integration $w_{n+1} = w_n + h \cdot f(t_n+ \alpha \cdot h, w_n + \alpha \cdot h \cdot f(t_n, w_n))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> Consider the initial-value problem: $$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}y'(t) = f(t,y(t)), \ \ \ t \geq 0,\\ y(0) = y_0. \end{array} \right. $$
>
> Now consider the numerical time-integration method: $$w_{n+1} = w_n + h \cdot f(t_n+ \alpha \cdot h, w_n + \alpha \cdot h \cdot f(t_n, w_n)), $$ where $h$ is the step size, $w_n$ is the numerical solution after $n$ steps and $\alpha \in [0,1]$.
>
> What is the order of the local truncation error for the numerical method described above and for which $\alpha$ does it have maximal order? Also, how would we determine the amplification factor from the test equation $$y' = \lambda y?$$

For the local truncation error, I tried computing $$\frac{y(t_{n+1}) - z_{n+1}}{h}, $$ where $z_{n+1} = y(t_n) + h \cdot f(t_n + \alpha \cdot h, \alpha \cdot h \cdot f(t_n, y(t_n))),$ but the argument of the function seems difficult to work with. I tried Taylor expanding the function, but I got nowhere (maybe I did in the wrong point, I tried to do it in $t_n$). Now, I simply don't know how to proceed. The same can be said about the amplification factor.

Comment: Please check again your formula, the second argument is missing its basis point. $$w_{n+1} = w_n + h \cdot f(t_n+ \alpha \cdot h, \color{blue}{w_n+}\alpha \cdot h \cdot f(t_n, w_n)).$$

Comment: Yes you are right, I will edit the post. Does this numerical method have a particular name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general two-stage explicit Runge-Kutta method
\begin{array}{c|cc}
0\\
α&α\\
\hline
&1-\beta&\beta
\end{array}
that is,
$$
w_{n+1}=w_n+\Bigl[(1−β)f(t_n,w_n)+βf\bigl(t_n+αh, w_n+αf(t_n,w_n)h\bigr)\Bigr]h
$$
satisfies automatically the order 1 order condition, and satisfies also the order 2 order condition if $βα=\frac12$. In your case, $β=1$.